# How does the angle of the faces of an object affect the degree it disperses light?

Tags: optics

I was wondering why convex (and concave) lenses do not appear to disperse light. I heard that due to the angle of the faces on either side of a convex lens, which are almost parallel, very little dispersion occurs. However, the source stated that since the angle between the faces of the prisms is much larger, dispersion occurs much more. Simply stated, I am wondering how the angle of the faces affect dispersion, as well as any other factors that play a part. I do not have much information on this topic and am studying for a science test, so I'm not sure if this is enough info.